# Using login data to make operations in other pages

Tags: php, html, authentication, using

I have a homework which is creating a web page which user can share photos or texts in their profile. But I am stuck at using login information to do it.

Here is my `login.html`:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
<br><label for="username">Username:</label></br>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<br><label for="password">Password:</label></br>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password">
<div id="lower">
<br><input type="submit" value="Login"></br>
<p>
Not yet registered?
 <a href="signup.html">Click here to register</a>

 </p>

</div><!--/ lower-->
</form>
```

and here is my login.php:

```
?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","webpage");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = $_POST['username'];  
$password = $_POST['password']; 

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'"); 
   if (!mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  die("You entered wrong username/password.");}

 while ($sql){

    $sql2="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' and approval = 1";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);    
    if (!$res) {
    echo "Your account isn't approved yet. Please wait for approval. Thanks :)";}
    else echo 'You have succesfully logged in.';
        header('Location: http://localhost/project2/redirect.html');
    }
mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

From here, I am stuck. I don't know what to do to use the username that the user has entered. What am I suppose to do?

Thanks.

Comment: you can set the username in session which can be used till the session is cleared..ie till the user logs out or close the browser..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the username in **session** which can be used till the session is cleared..ie till the user logs out or close the browser

> A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used
>   across multiple pages.
>
> Unlike a cookie, the information is not stored on the users computer.

By default, session variables last until the user closes the browser.

Thus, **Session variables hold information about one single user, and are available to all pages in one application**.

A session is started with the `session_start()` function.

Session variables are set with the PHP global variable: `$_SESSION`.

### To Set Session variables

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];  
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["uname"] =$username;
?>
```

### To Get Session variable's value

```
<?php
session_start();
$username =$_SESSION["uname"];
?>
```

### To Destroy the Session

```
<?php
// remove all session variables
session_unset(); 

// destroy the session 
session_destroy(); 
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But I didn't understand one point. I must give a $ description from somewhere. so where must I put $_session variable? into login.php or login.html?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies! Yum!

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Do some research here, try it out, and come back if you still can't get it.

Comment: I know cookies but in my university, but yet we haven't seen the javascript codes so most probably, my teacher will suspect :D